# Discord bot copy messages from server to my server

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

it's possible to copy new messages from X server Y channel to my X server Y channel, using bot in Discord? 
the server from which I want to copy the message is the official game server (on Discord) where I connect as a user, and my server is the guild server for this game where I want to send news and update announcements.

sorry for my English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This certainly is possible, using the `on_message()` event:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message) # add this if also using cmd decorators
    if message.channel.id == THEIR_CHANNEL_ID_HERE:
        target_channel = bot.get_channel(YOUR_ANNOUNCEMENT_CHANNEL_ID_HERE)
        await target_channel.send(message.content)
```

And of course you can add checks for file attachments, specific users, etc if you want to.

---

**References:**

- [`Bot.process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)
- [`TextChannel.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.id)
- [`Client.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)
- [`Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments)
- [`Member.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.id)

Comment: @Камаль No worries! Hope you get it working as you want it :) If the answer helped you out, if you wouldn't mind [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), as it could help other people seeking the same solution. Good luck with the bot!

Comment: @ Digig This program works fine, only on my server (where the bot is installed), if I understand this, the bot cannot connect to another server so it doesn’t have permission

Comment: The bot would need to be a member of another server in order to copy its messages - whatever channels it has access to, it will be able to copy messages from.